# What is the meaning of ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" in Tally XML Request

Tags: tally

What the meaning of

ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"

in tally xml request body.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know some of them.

TDL supports Object oriented programming and here are the [symbols](https://help.tallysolutions.com/developer-reference/tally-definition-language/what-are-symbols-and-prefixes-in-tdl/#general-symbols) and [modifiers](https://help.tallysolutions.com/developer-reference/definitions-attributes-modifiers/what-are-definitions-attributes-and-modifiers-in-tdl/) thar are related to this question.

- In TDL we can extend an existing definition using '#'

  for similar functionality in XML, we use ISMODIFY="YES"
- In TDL if we can create optional definitions using '!'

  for similar functionality in XML, we use ISOPTION="YES"
- In TDL if we can re-initialize definitions using '*'

  for similar functionality in XML, we use ISINITIALIZE="YES"
- I am not confirm about IsInternal , but I guess we use ISINTERNAL="YES", if are dealing with Internal definitions like internal objects
  [image: Intenal Objects]